# Python cypher: how to build a complexer shifter system?

Tags: python, encryption

I would like to build a cypher with python which decoding text by repeatedly travel through the numbers of the shifter from left to right and then from right to left and shift the letter in the alphabet by the corresponding number.

Example:

- shifter: 123
- text: `i like python`
- process: i+1=j, space, l+2=n, i+3=l, k+3=n, e+2=g, space, p+1=q, y+1=z, t+2=v, h+3=j, o+3=q, n+2=p
- result: `j nlng qzvjqp`

The code so far:

```
import string

numbers = ""

x = 3

while x < 10000:
    numbers = numbers + str(x)
    x += 1

shift = 221

#string.ascii_lowercase
letters = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation + numbers
text = (raw_input("Please enter text"))

encoded = ''
for letter in text:
    if letter == ' ':
        encoded = encoded + ' '
    else:
        x = letters.index(letter) + shift
        encoded = encoded + letters[x]

print encoded
```

It uses so far a basic coding method. I would love to know how is it possible to implement the above described encoding system in the code.

Comment: Warning this cipher is highly insecure.

Comment: An alternative would be RC4. It is a simple but powerful stream cipher. [Here](https://gist.github.com/2958701) is a Python implementation.

Comment: I copied your code to the question, to avoid extra clicking.

Comment: `rot13` is already implemented in Python: `>>> 'i like python'.encode('rot13')`
`'v yvxr clguba'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your version optimized (and working):

```
import string

shift = 221

letters = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation + string.digits
text = raw_input("Please enter text\n")

e = ''.join(letters[letters.index(l) + shift % len(letters)]
            if letters.index(l) is not None else ' ' for l in text)
print e
```

**Edit** The part with numbers was really wrong, because it added duplicate letters to your encoding sequence. This means that an encoded text cannot be decoded uniquely.

**Edit2**: If you want secure en/decryption, you need a modern algorithm like AES. If you want it implement on your own or understand the code, RC4 is a simple (but still secure if used correctly) alternative.

**Edit3**: Here is Vigenere in an optimized version:

```
from itertools import cycle, izip
from operator import add, sub
from string import printable as alphabet

def vigenere(text, key, mode='encode'):
    alen = len(alphabet)
    key = cycle(key + key[-2:0:-1])
    op = add if mode == 'encode' else sub
    return ''.join(alphabet[op(alphabet.index(c),
                               alphabet.index(k)) % alen]
                   for c, k in izip(text, key))

c = vigenere('attack at dawn', 'secret', mode='encode')
print c  # CHFBqN8BF8FoIO
print vigenere(c, 'secret', mode='decode')
```

Comment: This is Caesar, and he wants Vigenere (=different shifts for different letters) with an additional "pendulum" requirement.

Comment: @thg435 Oh, indeed. His code was Caesar encryption, though :)

Comment: @thg435 Added my own Vigenere implementation

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun here's an (intentionally verbose) [vigenere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) implementation with a "pendulum" key:

```
def pendulum(s):
    """Given abcd yields abcdcbabcdc... """
    while True:
        for p in s: yield p
        for p in reversed(s[1:-1]): yield p


def vigenere(text, key, mode='encode'):
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz '
    key = pendulum(key)
    encoded = ''

    for char in text:
        index = alphabet.index(char)
        offset = alphabet.index(next(key))

        if mode == 'encode':
            shifted = index + offset
        else:
            shifted = index - offset

        encoded += alphabet[shifted % len(alphabet)]
    return encoded

# test

print vigenere('attack at dawn', 'secret', mode='encode') # sxvrgcdrvdveyd
print vigenere('sxvrgcdrvdveyd', 'secret', mode='decode')
```

Let us know if you have questions.

Comment: @ms4py: yeah, always forget that python is not c ;)